# RESTEasy Seam integration application HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative path of full path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, seam, resteasy

I am trying RestEasy in jboss seam build application. What i did so far is 
updated components.xml

```
 <components xmlns:resteasy="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/resteasy"
             xsi:schemaLocation=
             http://jboss.org/schema/seam/resteasy
             http://jboss.org/schema/seam/resteasy-2.3.xsd
             http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components
             http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components-2.3.xsd">
```

My Resource class is

```
@Path("/customer")
@Name("customer")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
public class HelloWorldRestEasy
{
    @Path("/customerId")
    @GET
    public void getCustomer() {
        System.out.println("I am in hello world");

    }


}
```

I put jaxrs-api-2.0.1.GA, jboss-seam-resteasy , resteasy-jaxrs-2.0.1.GA in lib folder of war. As per documentation i do't need anything else(in my opinion).
But when i hit url. 
http://localhost:8080/seam/resource/rest/customer/customerId
It gives me error

"HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /customer/customerId of full path: http://localhost:8080/seam/resource/rest/customer/customerId"

Can any one help me what i am doing wrong or what i am missing i am stuck at this point from 3 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is an index.jsp accessible for your application @ http://localhost:8080/seam ?
And are you using Netbeans by any chance

Comment: Yes index page is accessible. Whole application is working as it was. But i have to put some restFul services, So when i configured restEasy it is not getting hit.
@Gyanapriya no i am using intelliJ IDE.

Comment: Alright, So this only means that the resource wasn't registered as expected. Do you have this in --`<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>` -- your web.xml ? 

If yes, the following should also be present : 
`<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
  <param-value>/rest</param-value>
 </context-param>`

Comment: Kindly do take a look @ http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/ just for your reference.

Comment: @Gyanapriya this is ok but as per documentation we do't need to configure this in web.xml. As Seam integrates well with restEasy we do't need to do any extra configurations. Seam will automatically look for reastEasy Resource on classPath (with annotation @path)

Comment: @Gyanapriya in case of Seam Application the stuff you mentioned we have to put in components.xml. Which i already did 
 <resteasy:application scan-providers="false"
                          scan-resources="true"
                          use-builtin-providers="true"
                          resource-path-prefix="/rest">
 <resteasy:resource-class-names>
<value>uk.co.iblocks.midas.resteasy.HelloWorldRestEasy</value>
 </resteasy:resource-class-names>
</resteasy:application>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76175/discussion-between-haseeb-wali-and-gyanapriya).